# Controller ngModel undifined in my custom directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I add a custom directive to my angular app which is in charge to verfy if the mail is valid or not, the directive seems working very well because  i got the error messages:

```
myApp.directive('validateEmail', function(ValidationService) {
    return {
      require: 'ngModel',
      controller: function($element) {
        var ctrl = $element.controller('ngModel');

        ctrl.$validators.validateEmail =
          function(modelValue, viewValue) {
            return ValidationService.isValidEmail(viewValue);
        };
      }
    };
});
```

when i tried to submit my form i got in the console the following strange error:

> Error: ctrl is undefined
>   controller@http://localhost:8080/MYAPP/js/app.js:293:9
>   invoke@https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.1/angular.js:4625:16
>   $ControllerProvider/this.$gethttps://code.angularjs.org/1.5.1/angular.js:9886:24
>   nodeLinkFn@https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.1/angular.js:8870:34
>   compositeLinkFn@https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.1/angular.js:8248:13
>   publicLinkFn@https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.1/angular.js:8128:30
>   compilationGenerator/<@https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.1/angular.js:8467:16
>   boundTranscludeFn@https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.1/angular.js:8266:16
>   controllersBoundTransclude@https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.1/angular.js:8963:20
>   ngIfWatchAction@https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.1/angular.js:25178:15
>   $digest@https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.1/angular.js:16728:23
>   $apply@https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.1/angular.js:16992:13
>   ngModelPostLink/<@https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.1/angular.js:26838:15
>   dispatch@http://localhost:8080/MYAPP/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js:3:10263
>   add/q.handle@http://localhost:8080/MYAPP/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js:3:

8325

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change controller to link.

```
myApp.directive('validateEmail', function(ValidationService) {
    return {
      require: 'ngModel',
      link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
        ctrl.$validators.validateEmail =
          function(modelValue, viewValue) {
            return ValidationService.isValidEmail(viewValue);
        };
      }
    };
});
```